# Getting the latest ETag before doing an update?

Tags: java, api, rest, http, etag

Currently my code makes a series of updates to some resource via a REST API but I also have some "rollback" logic that basically updates the resource to its original state before my updates if some kind of error happened. So in psuedo-code, the logic looks like:

```
public void doUpdate(Resource r) {
   // do a GET to get the latest eTag
   // make PUT call with eTag to do actual update
}

public void myLogic(Resource r) {
  Resource original = r;
  Resource copy = r.copy();
  try {
   doUpdate(copy);
   // do something to copy
   doUpdate(copy);
   // do some more things to copy
   doUpdate(copy)
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // rollback to original version
    doUpdate(original);
  }
}
```

This is a simplification of my actual code but my question is: Is it more correct to do GET before every update to get the latest eTag(as shown) or should I get the eTag once at the beginning and then "chain" the eTag I get from the prior update for the next update, including the rollback step?

Comment: FYI you can do a HEAD request instead to get the etag header in a response. It may save you downloading the whole body of the GET request. Also not sure why you're constantly updating the resource?

Comment: So you're saying that you're using the `ETag` value along with `If-Match` requests to do conditional updates? If so, it doesn't make sense to say you're getting the resource to get the `ETag`. You'd be getting the resource to see it's value, and then using the `ETag` to make sure you only overwrite the resource when it has that value. If you want to overwrite the resource regardless of its state when you fetch it, you're not doing conditional requests and don't need the `ETag` at all.